# Checks and balances in a 3 branch market economy

Tags: economy, government

There are 3 branches of "government":

1. Companies
2. Labor Unions
3. Consumer Unions

Companies make money by selling goods/services, Labor Unions make sure Companies compensate workers fairly, and Consumer Unions make sure Companies treat consumers fairly. Membership in a union is optional. Small businesses and free agent workers/consumers exist. They just may not get some negotiated benefits/deals.

Each union would be much more powerful than an individual person. This helps the **3 branches compete with each other** on an even playing field. However, I still want market forces. For this to happen, you need **competition between unions within the branches.**

How could each branch prevent the other two from consolidating into monopoly? For example, how could a Consumer Union stop a Labor Union from acquiring too many members? Some tools might include control over currency, hiring quotas, stock in companies, impeaching CEOs, strikes, and boycotts.

**Edit** Here is an example. There are 5 Companies, 5 Labor Unions, and 5 Consumer Unions. Each person belongs to 0-5 Consumer Unions, 1 Labor Union, works for 1 Company, and has stock in 0-5 Companies. The Companies give different health care packages based on which Labor Union you belong to, and give different discounts or features for their products depending on what Consumer Union you belong to. To join a union, you have to pay union dues. Large population with no barriers to communication.

The 3 branches don't have to perform all the duties of a full government, but we can give them any governmental duty if it would help with checking and balancing. That's why I put scare quotes.

Comment: What is the meaning of the word "government", complete with scare quotes, in this question? Because it surely does not mean, you know, government. Who enforces the rules? Who *sets* the rules in the first place? And, moreover, most natural persons will be at the same time direct or indirect shareholders in one or more corporations, members in a labor union, and consumers; how do they juggle their multiple hats? (You do know that corporations are by definition groups of people who associate for the purpose of doing business.) P.S. What do you mean by "not get the negotiated benefits"?

Comment: This looks like a (poorly researched) real-world brainstorming question rather than a worldbuilding exercise.  We know nothing about the size and nature of the population, technology level, geographic distribution etc, yet all of these things are critical to any answer.  The other issue is, as @AlexP points out, that you are talking about a "government" in the body but the title of the question is about a market economy.  Without better definition of terms and worldbuilding context this is likely to be closed as non-worldbuilding and/or requiring more details.

Comment: Most people work (labour union), most people consume. People who run companies don't work or consume? What would determine which union they'd belong to? What about shares in a company owned by a consumer and a labourer - strikes me as an under-specified question. Can you fill us in with clear detail.

Comment: What happens in your scheme if I start a company that is not one of the existing ones? If I do work usually locked up by one of the labor unions but refuse to join the union? I buy stuff but refuse to join the consumer union? You have brought us collective nouns without ever defining the things they collect.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you have is a fundamentally technical problem:

The Labor union are also the Consumer Union.

Maybe not in Membership explicitly - but the problem is that the majority of people who work for a living are also the majority of people who will buy things.

Immediately you've moved from a triumvirate system (which was your intention) to effectively a 2 against 1 system.

Now, you might consider that the competition of interests between each group would even this out - The consumer wants the cheapest price, the Labourer wants the highest wage and the Company wants the largest profit margin.

However, as we see in the west - Everyone always blames the company 'Waaaah Their profits are too high waaaaaaa' - and so again, you'd get the Labourers and Consumers (who are, in reality one and the same) ganging up on the Company.

Comment: People are in all 3 of these branches, not just 2. Companies consist of workers and stock holders. Sure, some people have high positions like CEO, but some people have high positions in unions as well.

Comment: You miss the point - The Consumer and the Worker are the same group, regardless of formal membership.

Comment: Then how are is a company not the same group?

Comment: @Stephen - The Company is controlled by a fraction of the people in it. This is a Maths problem - if you have a company of 100 people, realistically there are about 4 or 5 people who have any real say in the direction of the company (CEO, CFO, CTO and a couple of senior managers) - everyone else has very little input/decision making ability. Therefore, 4-5 people represent 'The Company' vs 95 people who are consumers and laborers.

Comment: @TheDemonLord So if it's 4-5 people on the one hand and 95 on the other, isn't it right for the 95 to get a lot more representation than the 5?

Comment: @causative - depends, what you've described is tyranny of the masses. Democracy is 3 Wolves and a sheep deciding what is for Dinner, Liberty is a well armed sheep contesting the vote.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Metaphorical tyranny of the masses or literal tyranny of the few, pick one. Somebody's going to wield political power and if it isn't the masses ruling, it is the few ruling over the masses. Usually you have a hundred sheep and one farmer deciding what's for dinner, and remember you're one of the sheep in this metaphor.

Comment: @causative - Tyranny is Tyranny. Whether against the many or against the few. This is why you need a defined limitation of government power(s) and an acknowledgement of Natural Rights. That's why in most western countries we don't have 'true, direct democracy' - we have some variant of it, to address that particular issue. As for who I am in the Metaphor - I assure you, I'm a well armed sheep.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Well, instead of arming the 99 sheep and depending on bloodshed to protect themselves from the 1 farmer exploiting them, how about they just form labor and consumer unions?

Comment: @causative - Exactly what is the difference between those two scenarios you've described? I'll give you a hint - there's no difference whatsoever. And then comes the real problem - what does the 1 farmer do then? One look at Zimbabwe or the Kulaks or Maos great leap forward tells us the answer - and it's even worse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145732/discussion-between-causative-and-thedemonlord).

Answer (score 2):

> How could each branch prevent the other two from consolidating into monopoly?

Same as today: by using **party politics**.

Each of the branches represents a juicy interest group that any party would love to add to its coalition. (And yes, it helps to think of *all* parties as coalitions of smaller interest groups which see coming together into an umbrella organisation as advantageous.) "Companies" would probably join a liberal party, "Labor" a socialist one and "Consumers" a conservative one. Within their corresponding parties, they would then need to compete with that party's remaining interest groups, all of which would want to put *their* agendas into the overall party policy; and then the parties would compete again to put their policies into practice.

All this competition would involve the usual political manoeuvring, compromising, tactical alliances etc. which would serve to dilute the initial position of any one interest group, including the government branches you mentioned. Because of this, consolidating two branches into a monopoly would actually be quite difficult to begin with, and not necessarily a big deal in the grand scheme of things even if it did happen.

Comment: I don't want all the Companies working together. There should be multiple companies competing with each other.

Comment: Question - why would Consumers be Conservative and why would Companies be Liberal? Generally Companies are more likely to tend towards traditional conservatism, whereas consumers are a mixed bunch.

Comment: @Stephen, thank you. They won't; after all, they would have their own competing interests despite their broadly similar ideological leanings.

Comment: @TheDemonLord, thank you. There aren't many countries with a pro-business conservative party, and those countries are mostly in the West, where *all* parties are unusually liberal.

Answer (score -4):

They can't. All history is the history of class struggle.

Comment: Care to expand on this? ('Twas in the Low Quality posts queue.)

Comment: @Joachim - it's just marxism 101 (and IMO that qualifies it as very low quality)

Comment: @TheDemonLord: It is actually *bad* Marxism. (It is a throwawy piece of rhetoric in an explicitly inflamatory tract.) Real Marxist Historical Materialism 101 is that history is fundamentally the history of the interdependent development of the means of production and of the relations of production.

Comment: @AlexP - which Marx considered to be a Class Struggle. Besides, bad Marxism is merely repeating the obvious